# convert unix executable file to plain text

Tags: unix

I see many people convert text to unix file. Is there some way to do the opposite, `unix executable file` to `.txt`?

(I need to read unix executable files under mac os. If it is impossible to convert the file, is there a way I can read them? `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 468: invalid start byte`
)

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the output of `file fileIwant2Convert`. (Do not add it as a comment, please). Good luck.

Comment: Please better explain what you are trying to achieve, like: are you trying to read binary files or trying to read shell-scripts, that are actually text-files.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that `nano` seems to convert to text automatically, although I want to be able to view it in a text editor, so I am still trying to find another way.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to read the file in Python, you need to append 'b' to the mode in order to avoid newline replacement.